# how do I insert output from othermodules/controllers in a view

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a view and I want to display data that would be generated by othe modules and controllers on the page.

What is the best way to do this?

For example:  If on a certain page I want to pull in the latest news from the news module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a view helper called [Action](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action) which allows you to call another controller's action (and display the markup generated).

I would add an action called latestNewsAction that renders a latest news panel/div/list and call that using the action view helper.

Comment: Does this work if the action/controller is in a different module?

Comment: Yep, and you can pass params in an array as the 4th parameter to the helper, especially useful if you need a way of telling the view to do something *slightly* different when it's called from another view!